Arduino UNO cannot connect to paj7620u2
I installed Arduino Uno with paj7620u2 as shown in the picture.

I tested with the following code and the result is initialization failed.
#include "RevEng_PAJ7620.h"

RevEng_PAJ7620 sensor = RevEng_PAJ7620();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!sensor.begin()) {
    Serial.print("PAJ7620U2 initialization failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  Gesture gesture = sensor.readGesture();

  switch (gesture) {
    case GES_FORWARD:
      Serial.println("FORWARD");
      break;
    case GES_BACKWARD:
      Serial.println("BACKWARD");
      break;
    case GES_LEFT:
      Serial.println("LEFT");
      break;
    case GES_RIGHT:
      Serial.println("RIGHT");
      break;
    case GES_UP:
      Serial.println("UP");
      break;
    case GES_DOWN:
      Serial.println("DOWN");
      break;
    case GES_CLOCKWISE:
      Serial.println("CLOCKWISE");
      break;
    case GES_ANTICLOCKWISE:
      Serial.println("ANTICLOCKWISE");
      break;
    case GES_WAVE:
      Serial.println("WAVE");
      break;
  }
}

I would like to check if my I2C is working properly, I tested an SSD1306 OLED Screen and the result is that it can display pictures and text properly.
#include <Wire.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.println("I2C Scanner...");
  for (byte address = 1; address < 127; address++) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

I've tried three brand new paj7620u2's and none of them are detected, I'm wondering if I'm making some kind of mistake and not finding them.

What is in your Serial monitor? Do you receive the message "PAJ7620U2 initialization failed"? It would also be a good idea to use pullup resistors for the I2C lines, since the ones provided by the Arduino board are often too weak

I using RevEng_PAJ7620 library, in Serial monitor show PAJ7620U2 initialization failed. Which pullup resistors do you suggest (How many kΩ?).

Maybe I need to use AMS1117-3.3 to let 3.3v be more stable?
